# shutdown of a remote linux system from my ubuntu

Tags: shutdown, systemd

I would like to shutdown a remote linux system, on a microzed card, from my pc when I shutdown it. To do this, I have done the following service for systemd. It should  operates when I send the shutdown/halt command to turn off my pc, but it does not work.

```
[Unit]
Documentation=
Description=Poweroff linux on zynq board
Requires=network.target
Before=shutdown.target reboot.target halt.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=true
ExecStop=/home/user/bin/zynqdown

[Install]
WantedBy=shutdown.target reboot.target halt.target
```

The zynqdown script simply sends the command:

```
ssh root@192.168.1.10 poweroff
```

The shell script launched into a shell works correctly.
I've looked at different forums and my service theoretically should work, but it seems like the command is sent when the network is already down.

Do you have suggestion about how to fix it?
Thanks
Claudio

EDIT:removed blanks not present into the code

Comment: I can see some blanks in the ExecStop= command. Is it me, or you typed too many blanks?

Comment: Use `After=network.target` so that on shutdown it is stopped before the network.

Comment: About the blanks, it is due to cut and paste.. In any case I will check the code.

Comment: I will try with the suggestion about after=... . I tried after=networking.service bu without good results. Thanks

Comment: I tried After=network.target, but no good results. The microzed card is still alive.